# Three days ON one day OFF schedule in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to set up a schedule for an habit such that the task has to be performed three days in a row and then skipped the fourth day. So, assuming the first recorded day is monday, I'll have:

```
Mon ✓ 
Tue ✓ 
Wed ✓ 
Thu x
Fri ✓ 
Sat ✓ 
Sun ✓ 
Mon x
etc.
```

Is it possible to set such a repeating schedule using the `.+` syntax?

Answer (score 2):

[tiny](https://github.com/abo-abo/tiny) can do this:

[image: tiny-schedule.gif]

Here's the thing to expand:

```
m\n10|** TODO Habit \nSCHEDULED: <%(date "Mon" (do31 x))>
```

Here's the yasnippet to produce something close to the above snippet:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: todo_schedule
# key: ts
# --
m\n${1:4}|`(make-string (org-current-level) ?*)` TODO $2 %(+ x 1)\nSCHEDULED: <%(date "${3:today}" (* x 7))>
```

Here's the code of `do31`:

```
(defun do31 (x)
  (+ x (/ x 3)))
```

You can do some variations as well:

```
m\n20|** TODO Habit \nSCHEDULED: <%(date "Mon" (do31 x))>
m\n20|** TODO Habit %(+ x 1)\nSCHEDULED: <%(date "Mon" (do31 x))>
m\n20|** TODO Habit %(+ x 1)\nSCHEDULED: <%(date "Mon 10:00" (do31 x))>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that `org-habit` has any concept of "Do it X times then skip Y times".

The closest I can see for approximating would be:  `.+1d/2` (Do every day, or at worst every second day).

Using multiple habits you could get the desired effect:

```
* TODO Habit
SCHEDULED: <2014-12-05 Fri .+4d>
:PROPERTIES:
:STYLE: habit
:END:
* TODO Habit
SCHEDULED: <2014-12-06 Sat .+4d>
:PROPERTIES:
:STYLE: habit
:END:
* TODO Habit
SCHEDULED: <2014-12-07 Sun .+4d>
:PROPERTIES:
:STYLE: habit
:END:
```

Comment: Yep, the multiple habits setup is how I'm workarounding the lack of proper support now. A proper feature would be a nice addition (at least for me since all my tasks seem to follow such patterns).

Comment: This would probably require a new iterator method (do X skip Y), or a set of properties for calculating the frequencies before skipping.